# Bluetooth Headset for Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, peripherals

If i go out an buy a bluetooth headset - one typically used for a mobile phone - will i be able to pair and use it with my mac mini (for skype/gtalk conerencing)? Im running OS X 10.5 on a last gen intel mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is most likely, assuming there is a bluetooth module in the Mac Mini ( which all new Minis should have )

You'll want to reference this [Apple Support Doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3563?locale=en_US) as well as [this one](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Bluetooth/1.0/en/blu26.html).

and also, if possible, check with the manufacturer first to be sure it's compatible.